# HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request between an AWS server to another AWS server but HTTP/1.1 200 between my local server and the same AWS server

Tags: php, http-status-code-400

## Reference

### PHP App1 AWS instances

AWSApp1Live (64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.4.6 running PHP 5.5)

AWSApp1Test (64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.3.2 running PHP 5.6)

### PHP App2 AWS instances

AWSApp2Live (64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.3.2 running PHP 5.6)

AWSApp2Test (64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.4 running PHP 5.5)

### Local App1 instance

LocalApp1 (Windows 10 running XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.1)

---

## Overview

I have two PHP applications: PHP App1 and PHP App2 which work together by communicating with eachother using internal POST requests. PHP App1 sends a request using

```
$query = http_build_query($data);
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' . PHP_EOL .
        'Cv-Forwarded-For: ' . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] . PHP_EOL,
        'content' => $query,
    ),
    'ssl'=>array(
        'verify_peer'=>false,
        'verify_peer_name'=>false
    )
));

$response = @file_get_contents(
    $target = $this->api_target.$action,
    $use_include_path = false,
    $context
);
```

PHP App2 is running a RESTful API service which responds to the requests sent from PHP App1. The response is a JSON string.

---

## Problem

I have loaded these PHP applications onto four different AWS instances as mentioned above. The following combinations of request/respone

**AWSApp1Live** communicating with **AWSApp2Live**

```
(HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request)
```

**AWSApp1Test** communicating with **AWSApp2Live**

```
(HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request)
```

**AWSApp1Test** communicating with **AWSApp2Test**

```
(HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
```

**LocalApp1** communicating with **AWSApp2Live**

```
(HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
```

So as you can see, PHP App2 when loaded onto **AWSApp2Test** and sent a request from **AWSApp1Test**, it responds with (HTTP/1.1 200 OK). But when loaded onto **AWSApp2Live** and given the same request from either **AWSApp1Live** or **AWSApp1Test** it responds with (HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request). The only time **AWSApp2Live** responds with (HTTP/1.1 200 OK) is when the request was sent from **LocalApp1**.

---

## Attempts to fix so far

1. We thought there might be something to do with the Zlib output compression setting on the **AWSApp2Live** software configuration, but the response was still the same.
2. We've done an nslookup from the **LocalApp1** server and the **AWSApp2Test** server for the **AWSApp2Live** server and both of them returned the same IP addresses to rule out any DNS issues
3. We SSH'd into the **AWSApp1Test** server and did a wget for one of the API commands on the **AWSApp2Live** server and we got back a JSON response which meant it is reaching the PHP application on that server.
4. There are no logs being generated on the **AwsApp2Live** server for me to see why the server is treating some requests as bad requests and others as not.
5. Using Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) I was able to successfully communicate with the API on **AWSApp2Live** so the application is running as expected.

---

## Any help would be greatly appreciated!

We are not sure where to look for any further clues as to what might be happening. If you need any further information please let us know. Thank you so much.

Comment: I would guess that some php configuration in the instances receiving the bad request is making your code generate an invalid post content to be sent. Compare your local configurations with the not working server configurations and see if you have something suspicious. This is only a guess.

Comment: Try using an array to set headers in `stream_context_create()`

Comment: @miken32 - Thanks a lot mate. Your suggestion worked. Can't believe it was something so simple. I guess I'll do some reading to find out why it was working on certain environment combinations and not others. Especially when developing on a local environment means things won't always work when on a production environment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php), but I think headers should be passed as a string only if there's a single one of them. Otherwise use an array:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => array(
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Cv-Forwarded-For: ' . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]
        ),
        'content' => $query,
    ),
    'ssl'=>array(
        'verify_peer'=>false,
        'verify_peer_name'=>false
    )
));
```

Comment: Still it's a concern when a certain configuration works in a specific environment and doesn't in another with the same code. Like how the request was responded to successully when it was made from my local server to the live API. And we keep a test instance on AWS just to test the code works in an AWS environment and it worked there as well (between the two AWSApp1Test and AWSApp2Test). It was only when the code bases were moved to AWSApp1Live and AWSApp2Live where it stopped working. And across all instances the PHP version was only .1 apart. Anyway, it's fixed. And thanks once again!

Comment: PHP_EOL will be different on Windows server.